# Two mysql query searches on same page?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

So I have two MySql searches on my jQuery mobile page but they do not work together.

Here is the code:

my index.php code:

```
<?php
    require "functions.php";

    $posts = getAllPosts();
    $posts = getSearchPosts();
?>

<?php 
    for( $p = 0; $p < count( $posts ); $p++ )
    {
?>

<div class="ui-corner-all custom-corners">
  <div id="searchpost">
    <?php echo $posts[$p]["search_role"];?>   <!-- using getSearchPosts -->
    <?php echo $posts[$p]["search_genre"];?>

    <?php echo $posts[$p]["user_first_name"];?> <!-- using getAllPosts -->
    <?php echo $posts[$p]["user_last_name"];}?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Functions.php:

```
function getSearchPosts()
{
    require "config.php";
    $posts = $c->query ( "SELECT * FROM posts" );

    if ( $posts->num_rows > 0 ) 
    {
        while( $row = $posts2->fetch_assoc() ) 
        {
            $postData[] = array( "user_id" => $row[ "user_id" ], "search_role" => $row[ "search_role" ], "search_genre" => $row[ "search_genre" ] );
        }
    } else {
        return "No Data";
    }
    return $postData;
}

function getAllPosts()
{   
    require "config.php";

    $posts = $c->query ( "SELECT * FROM users" );
    if ( $posts->num_rows > 0 ) 
    {
        while( $row = $posts->fetch_assoc() ) 
        {
            $postData[] = array( "user_id" => $row[ "user_id" ], "user_first_name" => $row[ "user_first_name" ], "user_last_name" => $row[ "user_last_name" ] );
        }
    } else {
        return "No Data";
    }
    return $postData;
}
```

I assume I am to change the `$posts` on one function to something else such as `$posts -> $search` or something but it does not echo anything after changing. What can I do to have both searches done at the same time?

Comment: You're using the same `$posts` variable for both function results. The second assignment replaces the first one, they don't merge.

Comment: Maybe you should do a single query that joins the two tables on the `user_id` column?

Comment: Why is the second function called `getAllPosts()`? It doesn't get anything about posts, it just gets all the users. It should be called `getAllUsers()`? And the first function doesn't do any searching, it just gets all posts.

Comment: It's unclear what you're really trying to do here. What is `$p`, and why would you use the same index into the array of posts and array of users?

Comment: getAllPosts used to get blog posts, I was gonna rename after I get everything working. The first doesn't do any searching because why add in the code to search when I can't even get the posts to show up? I use the same index for them as it is jquery mobile multipage: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/pages-multi-page/

Comment: Using multipage, I want to have the users on one page and the posts on another. But as it is jquery mobile it is all within one document.

Comment: Even if they're on the same page, you should display them separately. First get all posts, display them, then get all users, and display them. It makes no sense to mix them together.

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out how to do :S

Comment: Also, the $p code didn't show on post so I edited and changed it so it should now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do them as two separate loops. It makes no sense to show them both in the same DIVs, since there's no correspondence between the results of the two queries.

```
$posts = getSearchPosts();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    ?>
    <div class="ui-corner-all custom-corners">
    <div id="searchpost">
    <?php 
    echo $post['search_role']; 
    echo $post['search_genre'];
    ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
}

$users = getAllPosts();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    ?>
    <div class="ui-corner-all custom-corners">
    <div id="searchpost">
    <?php 
    echo $user['user_first_name']; 
    echo $post['user_last_name'];
    ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) I added it in and changed the names on the functions.php to match however on the inde.php I have an error :S  https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbLug.png

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/ct6014williams/public_html/pages-multi-page/index.php

Comment: It works perfect, thank you so much x I really do appreciate the help!